# Send Custom welcome email to specific user group

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

i want Send Custom welcome Email to specific user group

also i build a real estate site , and i want when a new buyer register to the buyer user group , also i want Custom email to be sent to him with some information ...

also i have already add this cod to the sb_welcome_email_editor but it don't work

// Change "from" email

```
 add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from_name' );

 function new_mail_from_name() {

 return 'hello@you-site.com';
 }

 // Change "from" name
 add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from' );

 function new_mail_from() {

 return 'Your site';
 }
```

can you help on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You have your functions mixed up - the new_mail_from is for the address, not the name, and the new_mail_from_name is for the name, not the address.

Also, WordPress changed the tests for users/groups from the old Roles to the new Capabilities so assuming your "buyer" user group has some specific Capability you can target then you could do something like this:

```
    // Change default WordPress email address for Buyers
    if(current_user_can( 'something_only_buyers_can_do' ) {
       function new_mail_from($old) {
       return 'hello@you-site.com';
     }
       function new_mail_from_name($old) {
       return 'Your Site';
     }
    add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
    add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');

    }
```

You could still try using the old Roles but no telling how long that will work, using Capabilities is more future-proof.